# Which probability distribution to use for relative abundance data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I am using the GLM model to understand the effects of environmental variables on habitat use of a species as I am taking the species relative abundance data as my response variable...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using the GLM model to understand the effects of environmental variables on habitat use of a species as I am taking the species relative abundance data as my response variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current description could be interpreted a number of different ways.  One approach is to model "relative abundance" as count data, e.g. how many deer are spotted on average per square mile.  These averages could be compared across different types of deer, e.g. bucks vs does.  This could be performed in a glm using a Poisson or negative binomial model.

"Relative abundance" might also refer to the proportion of one type of deer to another type, e.g. bucks vs does, in a given region.  This could be performed in a glm using a Bernoulli model for the relative proportions.

If you add clarity to your question the appropriate glm should also become clear.

Comment: If this person is coming from an ecology background, it is likely that 'relative abundance' means the count-based probability $\frac{n_i}{N}$ where $n_i$ is the number (abundance) of species $i$ and $N$ is the total number of individuals in a community of populations. I've encountered this is multiple textbooks, and it was standard terminology among ecotoxicologists that I worked with.

Comment: "How many deer are spotted on average per square mile" clearly is *not* "count data."  Assuming independent sampling, one should model the *raw* counts and use the log area as an offset with a log link.

Comment: I am describing the exposure-adjusted mean of the raw count data.